# PDE with Robin like boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Solve for $\phi:[0,L]\times [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \phi(x,t) &= c^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \phi(x,t) \\
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \phi(L,t) &= -r \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \phi(L,t) \\
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \phi(0,t) &= \boxed{\kappa_h \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t\partial x} \phi(0,t)} + \kappa_p \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \phi(0,t) \\
\phi(x,0) &= f(x) \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi(x,0) &= g(x)
\end{align*}
If the boxed term is missing, then $\partial\phi/\partial x$ satisfies Robin boundary conditions.  With the boxed term, using d'Alembert's method, I can show that there are solutions of the form
$$ \phi_n(x,t) = A_n \exp(w_n(t+x/c)) + B_n \exp(w_n(t-x/c)) ,$$
where $\text{Re}(w_n) < 0$ or $w_n = 0$.  (This is assuming $r, \kappa_h, \kappa_p > 0$.)  The solution is:
\begin{equation}
(\kappa_p + (\kappa_h - c) w_n)A_n = (\kappa_p + (\kappa_h + c) w_n) B_n
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\tanh(L w_n/c) = -\frac{c w_n(r + \kappa_p + \kappa_h w_n)}{r \kappa_p + r \kappa_h w_n + c^2 w_n^2} 
\end{equation}
For example, if $L = c = r = \kappa_d = \kappa_h = 1$, then using Mathematica the first few values of $w_n$ are:
$0$,
$-0.39382\pm1.41436i$,
$-1.00138\pm4.09326 i$,
$-1.30874\pm7.14689 i$,
$-1.49908\pm10.2568 i$,
$-1.63641\pm13.3829 i$,
$-1.74384\pm16.5156 i$,
$-1.83211\pm19.6515 i$.

Is it possible to show the set $\{\phi_n(x,0)\}$ are complete, that is, do they span $L_2[0,L]$?  And can one decompose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ into these $\phi_n(x,0)$ using something analogous to the Fourier coefficient formulas?  I already checked numerically, and it looks like the $\phi_n(x,0)$ are not orthogonal to each other.

Is there a general theory for this kind of stuff?  Even a reference would be very helpful.